# Send Parallel get request

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda

I'm trying to test a lambda function deployed at amazon aws. I want to send 200 request and calculate time they take to finish.Concurrency of my lambda function to 10 . However I encountered a service unavailable error when I send more than 10 requests at the same time. I want a way to divide my 200 requests into groups send first 10 requests first waiting for them to finish and send the second 10 and so on.
Any idea how I could implement that in python or node.js.

Comment: FIY, you can create a SQS in front of Lambda for this kind of task

Comment: I suggest you investigate why you got the "service unavailable error" error rather than trying to build a complex system as you describe.